# Do I need to install node.js to work with Ruby on rails?

Tags: node.js, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I just installed Ruby and then installed rails.
Created a new project.
and tried to run it.

It throws an error:

```
C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.3.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:95:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found C:/Users/user/Desktop/projects/Ruby/blog/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/name/Desktop/projects/Ruby/blog/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
```

After some research I understood it required Yarn which belongs to node.js

Is that the only solution?

Os :Win10

Comment: Where does [`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/) appear in that error message?

Comment: Upon installing Node.js and yarn it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set up node environment. node modules requires node `run-time`. `rails 6` uses `webpack`and yarn. here is more info: [a-rails-6-setup-guide](https://dev.to/vvo/a-rails-6-setup-guide-for-2019-and-2020-hf5)